# Is it possible to override .toString for a typed Java-Array in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, overriding, clojure-java-interop

I have a Byte-Array like so:

```
(def byte-arr (byte-array (map byte "This is a test"))) ; => #<byte[] [B@63465272>
```

When calling `.toString` I get `[B@1b96107b`. Is it possible to override the `.toString`-Method of the clojure type `[B` to get `This is a test` instead, in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bad idea to globally assume all byte arrays are a printable strings, thus the advice to  just use the String constructor is correct. That said, you *can* add new printing globally by type.

Printing functions eventually devolve to invocations of either `print-method` or `print-dup` multimethods, depending on whether `*print-dup*` is true. You can add a new method to `print-method` as follows using the `print-sequential` helper function in [core_print.clj](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core_print.clj):

```
(in-ns 'clojure.core)

(def ^:private ByteArray (type (byte-array 0)))

(defmethod print-method ByteArray [ba ^Writer w]
  (print-sequential "[" pr-on " " "]" ba w))
```

Note this just prints a byte array as if it were a vector of bytes:

```
clojure.core=> (in-ns 'user)
#<Namespace user>
user=> (byte-array (map byte "This is a test"))
[84 104 105 115 32 105 115 32 97 32 116 101 115 116]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend to override toString. It is too much global change and you might break some thing that relays on the default behaviour.

Why not creating a function for your specific requirement?

Comment: I never tried reify (nor can I state that I fully understand how it works, or where I would use it atm). But would it be possible to use reify for that usecase?

Comment: `reify` is suitable when you want a one time instance of some interface(s), protocol(s) and/or Object. `proxy` would be a better fit if it were possible to use it with Java's primitive arrays, but from my experience and the things I've tried, it doesn't seem to be. @AlexTaggart solution seems the best to me.

Answer (score 2):

Simply [construct a String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D%29) object with that byte array:

```
(println (String. byte-arr))
```